# Does Dojo has Label property for checkBox or its widgets?

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

I am creating a CheckBox in dojo as shown below-

```
new CheckBox({ 
 id:"chckBox", 
 checked: true, 
 label: "Save for future" 
},"divId").startup();
```

The checkBox has no label when it is displayed. It just has the checkbox checked. 
So my question is - Do I need to have 2 separate components to be laid out, one for checkBox and other one for the label ?? Can't I just combine this into 1 widget? 
Isn't there something similar to ExtJS where you have the fieldLabel property in dojo as well?

As well, say there is the no other way to create the check box with the label, other than having to input fields, then say if I need to do dynamic show/hide, do I need to apply CSS property on both the widgets separately,right ?

Please let me know if I am wrong.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are all right.

There is no "checkbox with label" widget in DOJO, you need to create them separately and style them separately as well.

Comment: Is this true for all the form components widgets ?? If so, why doesn't dojo add a property as 
         'fieldLabel' 
or something similar to the objects?

Comment: @unix_user No, this is not true for all form component widgets. There is a "label" property for Button, RadioButton, ToggleButton. But for checkbox, textbox, filteringselect, no "Label" and you need create your own.

Comment: So it goes to comboBox as well with no label property.

Comment: @unix_user Yes, no label for comboBox as well. A correction for my previous comment, no label for RadioButton since RadioButton inheriate Checkbox.